# Fetch single commit with LibGit2[Sharp]

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

How can I do the equivalent of `git fetch origin <CommitHash>` with LibGit2Sharp?

It seems the only relevant option for git_remote_fetch are the refspecs so I imagine I need some trickery there, but I don't see how from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

The idea is to fetch only the data required and not everything from the remote since the repo is a shallow clone.

Comment: LibGit2Sharp doesn't support yet shallow clones (cf. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/229)

Comment: @nulltoken If you want you can just copy that to an answer and I'll accept it.